# MVC5: Exception with "TryUpdateModel"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to use TryUpdateModel to restrict the properties updated by the edit method.

I want users to see all the fields in the Edit form but don't want the Title property of the Album entity to be updated. So I'm doing this:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit()
        {
            var album = new Album();
            TryUpdateModel(album, new[] { "Price","Date","Genre"});
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(album).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }.....
```

When executing this code, I am having an error on db.SaveChages(), which says:

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected
>   number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since
>   entities were loaded. See
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on
>   understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it's saying that 0 rows were modified by your update. So, your primary key (whatever makes a row unique) points to an ID that does not exist in the database. You need to figure out why this is happening and instead use a key that exists in the database.

Comment: Should I inclue the primary key with the TryUpdateModel? Is it obligatory?

Comment: @BrittanyRutherford that's a good question that I don't know the answer to. I'd say try it and see if it works?